# Using Armory Watch-Only wallet in Electrum?

Tags: electrum, armory, coldstorage, watch-only

Is it possible to import a Watch-Only wallet that was made in Armory into Electrum?

I like to use Armory for cold storage but like Electrum more for hot wallets because it's lightweight and you never have to sync. Is there a way I can import my cold storage wallet's watch-only copy that was made with Armory into Electrum on my personal computer?

Answer (score 1):

They're different formats, so no.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to export bitcoin adddress in your wallet. You can also use services like http://www.blockonomics.co to monitor your cold storage